# Javascript: How can I use splice() on an array to move a specific word?

Tags: javascript

This is the code I have - can you please tell me what is wrong? I would like to remove a specific word from the array using splice, in this case "tree".

```
var array = ['dog', 'man', 'tree']
array.splice(array.indexOf('tree'));
```

Comment: `array.splice(array.indexOf('tree'), 1);` second parameter tells how many to delete.

Comment: Beside specifying how many elements should be deleted you should also make sure that `array.indexOf(...)` doesn't return `-1` otherwise `splice(-1, 1)` will remove the last element.

Answer (score 3):

The second argument to `splice` is the number of items to delete.

```
array.splice(array.indexOf('tree'), 1);
```

otherwise all following elements are deleted.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 2):

You also have to provide an argument specifying how many items to delete. Otherwise, all elements from the specified start index will be removed.

```
array.splice(array.indexOf('tree'), 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just filter it:

```
const withoutTree = array.filter(word => word !== 'tree')
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript splice method works with index to be deleted and item to be deleted.
In your case-

```
var newArray =  array.splice(2,1);
console.log(newArray);// outputs ['dog','man']
```

Here 2 is the index of the element to be deleted which is 'tree' in your case and the second argument defines the number of element to be deleted.